# Casper folder too full

Tags: filesystem

I have Elementary OS 6.1 (20.04.6 LTS) running in VMware Pro 17.0.2

Files shows me a mount of '/media/username/elementary os' with no space left (used 2.7gb of 2.7gb). There is a file of 2.5gb '/media/username/elementary os/casper/filesyste,.squashfs'.

What can I do about it?

Comment: A `.squashfs` file is a compressed file system image; a "squashed file system", if you will. These generally grow and shrink as required. If you are seeing messages about a lack of space, the host may be running low on space 